# Accessing large data sets in AWS rstudio

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, rstudio-server

Apologies if this is a naive question or not the correct platform to ask, new to AWS, not finding answers online, and this site has help with r challenges before.

I am working with sequencing data in r (dada2 package). Based on some research, using AWS EC2 rstudio seemed like a good approach for me since I do not have access to servers at my institution. I uploaded my data files from an external drive to S3. My challenge is how to work with the multiple large files in r. From what I understand, you cannot use S3 as a working directory, just as a location to store the files. I also believe r has a memory limitation of 1 GB. I have multiple files that total approximately 13 GB. So reading the files into r is not a solution. Any suggestions around this, other solutions, or tutorials available?

I have looked into several packages for working with data in r that is stored on S3 (paws and aws.s3) but they only seem useful for reading and writing files, not allowing you to essentially set s3 as a working directory, which I have also read is not possible using AWS for rstudio. I have not found a way to set a working directory outside of the r home file, which has space limitations. I do not necessarily have to use s3 if there is a better way to store and access the data for r. I could also realize I could probably load and process the sequence files individually but was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Comment: *"I also believe r has a memory limitation of 1 GB"* I don't know where you got that idea, but it is wrong. The main reason to use an EC2 is that it has more memory than your laptop (which probably has 4 or 8 or even 16 GB). R can use as much memory as your computer has. If your EC2 has, say, 32 GB of memory reading 13 GB in to R should be fine.

Comment: You also seem to think that a "working directory" is something more special than it is. It is just the default file path for R to read and write files. If your files were on your local machine and in your working directory, you would need to read them in to R to use them. If they were on your local machine and not in your working directory, you could still read them in to R to use them. If they are on S3, you still need to read them in to R to use them.